# vim delete till one character before the end of the line

Tags: regex, vim

I can press `$` to go to the end of the line so if I want to delete everything till EOL I can do `d$` (or `D`). What if I want to delete till EOL column - 1 character (or - n chars more broadly)?

### Example

I have a row `1234.567890` where `.` represents the cursor and want `1234.0` (`.` represents cursor again).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no identical character in between (or the number of those is easily determined), the `f` and `t` commands are very useful, because they just involve two keystrokes (the command and the target character, possibly prepended by a `[count]`), and (unlike the more generic `/...<CR>`) they are limited to the current line. For your example, that would be `dt0` then.

For more complex scenarios, before I stop and lengthily contemplate possible solutions, *visual mode* is a quick alternative that lets you **iteratively fine-tune the area** before applying the command. I think it's a great pragmatic addition to the original command set of *vi*. For your example, that would be `v$hd`.

Comment: I've decided to make this one the solution since the visual mode is really versatile.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
d/.$<CR>
```

This deletes until one character before EOL.

Answer (score 1):

There is no  built-in movement for that, but  you can create
your  own  easily  with  `:omap`.  It  will  work  with  any
operator.

```
:onoremap <silent> q :<C-U>normal! v$hh<CR>
```

Now `dq`  will do what you  want, as well as  `cq` to change
until the before-last char, `vq`, `yq` and so on.

This  works by  replacing `q`  with a  call to  `:normal` to
initiate  a visual  selection, up  to  the end  of the  line
(`v$`) and  back two characters (that's  because `$` selects
until the  newline itself). The `<C-U>`  clears any possible
range.